# iPad Restkit and OData Microsoft SQL AZURE

Tags: sql, insert, azure, odata, restkit

I'm developing an ipad app and I need to save some data in OData SQL Azure,
I know how to get data sending requests with querys but I don't know how to send a post
request to insert to OData, I don't know how to create the xml to send along with the request

I've been looking for information in OData.org but I don't quite get it.

Could anyone tell me how I should accomplish this?

Thanks!!! XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look into the [OData Client for Objective-C](http://odataobjc.codeplex.com/)?

You should be able create your entities locally on the client in an ObjectContext, then call saveChanges.

Comment: Yes I'd already downloaded it but I was trying to use any other simple way to send the request, to retrieve data from odata I only have to send a simple request with a query within it, I was expecting I could find a similar way to insert data, guess there's no such way. Now could you help me understand how I create the proxy classes? It says in the docs that there's a command line tool to generate them but I don't know how. Sorry I don't get this well and thanks a lot for your time. XD